# Naming sheets with workbook name after merging?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got over 200 workbooks that I need to merge, the code below will merge the workbooks and add all the sheets into one workbook.

In that workbook the sheets are being named `Sheet 1 (1)`, `Sheet 1 (2)` and so on.

If the sheet was copied from `Workbook1` the sheet name would be `workbook 1`

```
Sub mergeFiles()
    'Merges all files in a folder to a main file.
    'Define variables:

    Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
    Dim tempFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet

    Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
    tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show

    'Loop through all selected workbooks
    For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
        'Open each workbook
        Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i)
        Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

        'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
        For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
            tempWorkSheet.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        Next tempWorkSheet

        'Close the source workbook
        sourceWorkbook.Close

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the names of the sheets in you Target Wb (mainWorkbook)? Do the Source WB-s (tempWorkSheet) only contain 1 Sheet ("Sheet1")? Is the code in mainWorkbook?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you `For Each` loop

```
Dim j as integer ‘Add to top of your sub
j = 0 ‘Add inside for loop 

For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
    j= j+1
    tempWorkSheet.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = sourceWorkBook.Name & “ - “ & j ‘Added Line of code to rename copied tab
Next tempWorkSheet
```

As long as your workbook names aren’t too long or duplicate, it should be good

Comment: Hi, I want it to take the name of the workbook not the worksheet.

Comment: Thank you this works, for around 20 sheets and then I get an error "Cannot rename a sheet with the same name as another sheet" - All names are different and non of them are the same so I'm no too sure why I'm getting that error. any idea (all names are 6 characters long)

Comment: I updated to code to now include and integer at the end of the sheet name. If you are copying more than 1 sheet from the sourceBook you’ll need to differentiate the imported tabs

Comment: @Fawnlemur if this answered your question, please mark as answered and upvote please

Answer (score 0):

## Merge Files

### Code Issues

You have declared `numberOfFilesChosen` as `Variant`:

```
Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer ' Wrong
```

> ```
> Dim numberOfFilesChosen as Integer, i As Integer ' OK
> ```

You have declared `mainWorkbook` as `Variant`:

```
Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook ' Wrong
```

> ```
> Dim mainWorkbook as Workbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook ' OK
> ```

Such a code should be in the Workbook (`mainWorkbook`) where the
   Worksheets are being imported, so you don't need a variable, just use
   `ThisWorkbook`. Then in combination with the `With` statement, you
   can use e.g. `.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)`.

You are changing between sheets and worksheets. When you use `mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`, this might not necessarily be the last sheet, so it would be more correct to use `mainWorkbook.Sheets.Count` especially for the added sheet counter to function correctly.

```
tempWorkSheet.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
```

> ```
> tempWorkSheet.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Sheets.Count) ' Preferable
> ```

When you use `sourceWorkbook.Close`, you might be asked to save the workbook. Using

> ```
> sourceWorkbook.Close False ' Preferable
> ```

will close the workbook without saving changes.

> The code will fail if you run it another time, because the sheet names
>   it will try to create are the same. Therefore I have added
>   `DeleteWorksheetsExceptOne` which I used while testing the code.

### The Code

```
Sub mergeFiles()
    'Merges all files in a folder to a main file.

    'Define variables:
    Dim tempFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet
    Dim numberOfFilesChosen As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
    tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show

    With ThisWorkbook
        'Loop through all selected workbooks
        For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
            'Open each workbook
            Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i)
            Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
            j = 0

            'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
            For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
                j = j + 1
                tempWorkSheet.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
                ' Rename newly added worksheet to the name of Source Workbook
                ' concatenated with "-" and Counter (j).
                .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = sourceWorkbook.Name & "-" & j
            Next

            'Close the source workbook. False for not saving changes.
            sourceWorkbook.Close False
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

### Delete All Worksheets But One

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:  Deletes all Worksheets in the ActiveWorkbook except one.
' Danger:   This code doesn't ask anything, it just does. In the end you will
'           end up with just one worksheet (cStrWsExcept) in the workbook
'           (cStrWbPath). If you have executed this code and the result is not
'           satisfactory, just close the workbook and try again or don't. There
'           will be no alert like "Do you want to save ..." because of the line:
'           ".Saved = True" i.e. "objWb.Saved = True".
' Arguments (As Constants):
'   cStrWbPath
'     The path of the workbook to be processed. If "", then ActiveWorkbook is
'     used.
'   cStrWsExcept
'     The worksheet not to be deleted. If "", then the Activesheet is used.
'*******************************************************************************
Sub DeleteWorksheetsExceptOne()

  Const cStrWbPath = ""          ' if "" then ActiveWorkbook
  Const cStrWsExcept = "Sheet1"  ' if "" then ActiveSheet

  Dim objWb As Workbook
  Dim objWsExcept As Worksheet
  Dim objWsDelete As Worksheet

  If cStrWbPath = "" Then
    Set objWb = ActiveWorkbook
   Else
    Set objWb = Workbooks(cStrWbPath)
  End If

  With objWb
    If cStrWsExcept = "" Then
      Set objWsExcept = .ActiveSheet
     Else
      Set objWsExcept = .Worksheets(cStrWsExcept)
    End If

    ' To suppress the "Data may exist in the sheet(s) selected for deletion.
    '                  To permanently delete the data, press Delete." - Alert:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

      For Each objWsDelete In .Worksheets
        If objWsDelete.Name <> objWsExcept.Name Then
          objWsDelete.Delete
        End If
      Next

      ' To suppress the "Do you want to save changes you made to ... ?" - Alert:
      .Saved = True

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  End With

End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
```